# jQuery hide parent block if all childs hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The question is how to hide parent block if all childs are hidden, **and display it if they are visible again**?
Is it possible to "monitor" block status with jQuery?

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YhqW8/) - here red block must automatically hide if we hide yellow and green blocks.

**Html**

```
<div id="mother">
    <div class="child1"></div>
   <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mother {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}

.child1, .child2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: orange;
}

.child2 {
    background:green;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    var childs = $("[class^=child]");

    childs.click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var childs = $("[class^=child]");

    childs.click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        //check if any child is visible, if not hide the mother element
        if(!childs.filter(':visible').length){
            $('#mother').hide()
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kSwjx/)

Comment: Thank you, but question is how to disabled red block again if one or all of child elements are visible

Comment: @Nerfair then you need to implement a similar logic where you are making the child visible again

Answer (score 2):

You can check the length of visible elements inside `#mother` div by using **[:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** selector along with `.length`, if it's equal to `0` then hide `#mother`:

```
$(function () {
    var childs = $("[class^=child]");
    childs.click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        if ($("#mother").find(":visible").length == 0) 
            $("#mother").hide();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YhqW8/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this in child click event handlers:

```
   if($('#mother').children(':visible').length == 0) {
      $('#mother').hide();
   }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YhqW8/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try so:

```
$(function() {
    var childs = $("[class^=child]");

    childs.click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        var $child = $parent.find('div:visible');

        if(!$child.length){
           $parent.hide();
        }
    });
});
```